# How to resolve "Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated." for InMobi Unity Mediation Plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, inmobi, mobile-ad-mediation

I am trying to implement google-admob mediation and currently working on Integrating InMobi ads. I followed all the steps as per https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediation/inmobi .I was able to create the Account ID and Placement ID in the inMobi website . I successfully was able to configure AdMob ad unit in my admob account.

The problem is in the 3rd step of the process which is "Import the InMobi SDK and adapter". I extracted the latest version of Google Mobile Ads mediation plugin for InMobi from this link https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediation/inmobi#inmobi-unity-mediation-plugin-changelog .

But while performing this step  Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Force Resolve , I am getting the following "Android Dependencies , Resolution failed" error. I am attaching the screen shot and the log file below. I tried to change the version of the InMobi Unity Mediation Plugin some 5 times,but all the time it keeps failing. I changed to  stack trace to full and understand but still can't really figure out what to do.

For inMobi ad mediation for unity there is no video on youtube also. Please help me to figure out the solution for this problem.

[image: Android Dependencies , Resolution failed Error]

Log files details:

Running Gradle...

```
C:\Users\cheth\FlutteringBirds1\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat --no-daemon -b "C:\Users\cheth\FlutteringBirds1\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.1.6f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=C:\Users\cheth\FlutteringBirds1\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=file:///C:/Users/cheth/FlutteringBirds1/Assets/Firebase/m2repository;https://maven.google.com/;https://jcenter.bintray.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.5.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2;com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:7.1.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1;com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-unity:7.1.0;com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0;com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:9.1.1.0" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=1" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=3.6.0"
Executing command: C:\Users\cheth\FlutteringBirds1\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat --no-daemon -b "C:\Users\cheth\FlutteringBirds1\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.1.6f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=C:\Users\cheth\FlutteringBirds1\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=file:///C:/Users/cheth/FlutteringBirds1/Assets/Firebase/m2repository;https://maven.google.com/;https://jcenter.bintray.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.5.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2;com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:7.1.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1;com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-unity:7.1.0;com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0;com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:9.1.1.0" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=1" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=3.6.0"
Reporting analytics data: /androidresolver/resolve/gradle/failed/fetch?unityVersion=2021.1.6f1&unityPlatform=WindowsEditor&installSource=upm&version=1.2.164&scope= 'Android Resolver: Gradle Resolve: Tool Extraction Failed'
ERROR: Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.

Failed to run 'C:\Users\cheth\FlutteringBirds1\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat --no-daemon -b "C:\Users\cheth\FlutteringBirds1\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.1.6f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=C:\Users\cheth\FlutteringBirds1\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=file:///C:/Users/cheth/FlutteringBirds1/Assets/Firebase/m2repository;https://maven.google.com/;https://jcenter.bintray.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.5.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2;com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:7.1.0;com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1;com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-unity:7.1.0;com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0;com.google.ads.mediation:inmobi:9.1.1.0" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=1" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=3.6.0"'
stdout:

stderr:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValueFactory.<clinit>(GroovyClassValueFactory.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.<clinit>(ClassInfo.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.<clinit>(ReflectionCache.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:209)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.getDefaultMetaClass(GroovyObjectSupport.java:59)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.<init>(GroovyObjectSupport.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.<init>(DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention.<init>(DefaultConvention.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ExtensibleDynamicObject.<init>(ExtensibleDynamicObject.java:58)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.<init>(DefaultSettings.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.DirectInstantiator.newInstance(DirectInstantiator.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsFactory.createSettings(SettingsFactory.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.process(PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.java:37)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.process(SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.initialization.RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.process(RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:48)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.process(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:104)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:45)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.composite.CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$LoadBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:277)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.loadSettings(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:202)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:147)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.execute(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$3.create(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:183)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:207)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:403)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:376)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:23)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:369)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:299)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated.
> Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 29):

It's a bug that has existed for years. Maybe we've been dealing with this since the 2017 release. But unfortunately, it is not even clear what Unity is doing about it.

To solve: Edit->Preferences->External Tools

In the window that opens, you must remove the checkboxes at the bottom and give the same paths! It's ridiculous, but yes, it's true!!!

[image]

Good luck, we need it.

Comment: That's actually it, no way!!! Still happening in Unity 2021.3.14f1, this fixed the problem

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. Also, make sure to restart Unity after unchecking. My Unity version 2021.3.17f1

Comment: Once it helped. but now it does not help

Comment: unbelivable it works still in Unity 2022.3.2f1 thx.

Comment: This is VERY HIGH UP in the list of stupid bugs that I've seen in my whole life. Unity 2023 and still going strong.

Comment: this should be marked as the answer

Comment: Works. Happened to me with Unity 2022.3.10f1 Silicon.

Answer (score 0):

In my case switching Edit->Preferences->ExternalTools->JDK from default OpenJDK to manually installed old [Oracle JavaSE8 JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html) helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message and tried a lot of things to fix it. Finally updating Java from jdk-17 to jdk-19 fixed it. I also updated the environment variables

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19
```

and

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin
```

Note that the PATH variable actually contains many more paths from other programs on my system. A windows logoff and login is required for the changes to take effect.

Comment: What do you mean PATH? Where need to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following three things.

- Followed Erçin Dedeoğlu instructions. (Nothing Happened)
- Had JDK 21 and downgraded to JDK 19. (Nothing Happened)
- Toggled the "Stop Gradle Daemons on exit" option. (Worked)
  [image]